# Do you have to declare mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps everytime you want to access the state in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I am just using redux and I have a question about whether I have to declare mapState and mapDispatch every time I want to access to the redux state

I have set up redux with its store, and actions/action creators/types. I also utilized the connect HOC function from the react-redux library. I have two components, both sharing the state and actions. Do I have to pass the mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps and connect function as well everytime I want to access these properties? I know there is redux-hooks that can do this, but I am asking for without the hooks. I will provide code below. Thanks!

```
// CarContainer

import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {BUY_CAR, SELL_CAR} from "./carActions";

const buyCar=()=> {
    return {
        type: BUY_CAR
    }
}

const sellCar =()=> {
    return {
        type: SELL_CAR
    }
}

const CarContainer = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h5>Number of Cars: {props.numOfCars}</h5>
            <button onClick={props.buyCar}>Buy Car</button>
            <button onClick={props.sellCar}>Sell Car</button>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        numOfCars: state.numOfCars
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        buyCar: ()=> dispatch(buyCar()),
        sellCar: ()=> dispatch(sellCar())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CarContainer);




// LoseCar container


import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { SELL_CAR } from "./carActions";

const sellCar =()=> {
    return {
        type: SELL_CAR
    }
}

const LoseCar = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h5>Number of Cars: {props.numOfCars}</h5>
            <button onClick={props.sellCar}>Sell Car</button>
        </div>
    )
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        numOfCars: state.numOfCars
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        sellCar: ()=> dispatch(sellCar())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(LoseCar);



// App Container


import React from 'react';
import CarContainer from "./redux/cars/CarContainer";
import LoseCar from "./redux/cars/LoseCar"
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CarContainer />
      <LoseCar/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: You could use reselect to prevent repeating code, duplicate implementatin of where information in your state and assuming what shape it's in is pretty bad design for large apps. The mapDispatch can be simpler and you can just pass an object: `const container = connect(selectProps, {buyCar, sellCar}); const ConnectedCarContainer = container(CarContainer); const LoseCarContainer = container(LoseCar)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a connector in one file so you don't have to write the same logic multiple times.

```
export const connectCars = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps);
```

Then in another file, you can use just

```
export default connectCars(LoseCar);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i get it right, but according to [React Redux Doc](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/):

1- `mapStateToProps`:
is used for selecting the part of the data from the store that the connected component needs. That way, if you want to use some part of your store as a read-only variable that will be updated by itself, you go for `mapStateToProps`.

2-`mapDispatchToProps`:
is used for dispatching actions to the store. So if you want to change any value inside your store you go for `mapDispatchToProps`.

You don't need to use none of them if you will not interact with your store inside the Component. Also, you can have only one of those. Like that:

if you don't need to read any value:

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CarContainer);
```

or

if you dont need to change any value:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(CarContainer);
```